# Which is right way to use below statement performance wise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Which approach is most recommended. First or Second ?

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("span");

// #1:  Console returns false
x.length > 0 && x[0].blur();

// #2:  Console returns undefined
if (x.length > 0) {
  x[0].blur();
}
```

Comment: They are identical, but the second is more readable.

Comment: the second, becaus the readability is greater, and the result of the expression is never used (in the first case).

Comment: They're identical, logically. It's just down to which you find more readable

Comment: 2nd is more wise

Comment: 2nd is recommended from readability point of view as both are identical.

Comment: Technically both approaches are the same. However, the second one has a better readability

Comment: @NinaScholz Expression is never used ur right thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you find `x.length > 0` then you will definitely get `x[0]` and do not need to check `&& x[0].blur();`. So your second approach is much better.

```
if (x.length > 0) {
  x[0].blur();
}
```

Comment: He is not checking for `x[0]` as mentioned in your answer. He is calling `blur()` method on the first element of the array, when array is not empty. The question asked has no logical difference and achieves the same result, it is about what is the best way out of these two.

Comment: Yes x[0] also indicates the first element of an array.